# Can we build Skype bots for "Skype for Business"?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, skype-bots, microsoft-skype-bot

I've seen examples of bot programming that work with "Skype". Is it possible to develop enterprise bots that run on "Skype for Business" using Microsoft's Bot/Cognitive service tools/framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Skype for Business is not yet supported by [Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com/). To find all the messaging channels that are supported visit the Bot Framework's [documentation site](http://docs.botframework.com/).

Answer (score 5):

The Microsoft Bot Framework now officially supports Skype for Business as a channel:

- [Skype for Business Bot Framework (Preview)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/skype-for-business-bot-framework/docs/overview)

(As of writing this its in Preview mode, so things may change in the future. But at least its there.)

Answer (score 4):

Skype for Business does use UCWA (Unified Communications Web API), though the documentation is pretty dated it is possible to have a user account for the bot and use the API calls for direct messaging.

This also requires some knowledge of the server that your Skype for Business is running through.

Comment: Do you have any pointer for the API calls? I've found a lot of stuff about authenticating (very confusing and very dated) but very little for chatting - endpoints, parameters etc.

Answer (score 1):

Further going thru the Build 2016 videos and Microsoft support site reveals Skype bot programming is limited to consumer skype and not for "Skype for Business".  It seems microsoft has future plans to bring this to "Skype for Business"

Comment: Do you have any links to that statement?  You have it in quotes like you're taking it directly from a source

Comment: Here it is : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/70656a60-4072-479f-9e0c-8863652e99f5/question-about-direction-re-skype-for-business-bots?forum=SkypeWebSDK&tduid=(d31bbe2aa97451a9a64ff74983f1e13f)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-kgwdQcnBMSZfZzDV5Hu8xw)()

Answer (score 1):

Yes, bots can be built for skype for business, please have a look at the following link. 
http://acuvate.com/blog/chatbots-on-skype-for-business/