# How to setup UCMA Development environment locally for Lync 2010?

Tags: c#, lync-2013, ucma, lync-2010, lync-server-2010

I have created a chat bot in c#. But the requirement has changed to a bot that can be directly accessed through lync. Lync is present in our network, but the server is separate and my development environment is not at the server side. I have a few questions on the scenario :-

- I have to create an application endopoint. Is UCMA the best way to
  go?
- Is UCMA free?
- How do I set up my development environment so that I can test my bot
  without affecting the other lync users?
- Is it possible to make my local system the server, add it to the trusted server list in the actual lync server, add my application endpoint to the trusted application pool in the actual lync server.Would I need anything else if I follow this route?
- I have lync 2010. Will UCMA 4.0 SDK work for lync 2010?

Answer (score 0):

1. Skype / Lync offers UCMA & UCWA. However it depends on your application which might be the best one. Without having more details what you try to build its not easy to answer that. See this posting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904497/can-we-build-skype-bots-for-skype-for-business) for more infos.
2. You need a Skype/Lync environment. This required a valid license.
3. You might try an evaluation version from the Microsoft evalcenter [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-skype-for-business-server). You can have only one lync or Skype for Business environment in your active directory. But you can setup an additional pool. However to avoid that you break something I highly recommend to setup a separate developer environment
4. Keep noted that Lync 2010 is quite very old. There is Lync 2013 already in place and got replaced with Skype for Business. Building something on Lync 2010 which is 6 years old didn´t sound a good idea. However UCMA 4.0 and UCMA 5.0 are supported (as written [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn962207(v=office.16).aspx)) by Skype for Business, so your might wish to check if you will not build that for Skype for Business instead.

Comment: I know lync 2010 is pretty old, but that is what is used in our organization. I  already have a chat bot but since its a difficult job to connect lync to it, I was planning to create a bot( application endpoint ) for lync using UCMA. Problem is, I do not have access to the server where lync is hosted. This is for a poc. So, I don't think I will get the access to the server. If the POC is approved, in the later stages I might get that approval. But for the purpose of poc( proof of concept ) I need to create a working copy to prove that its worth wile. Skype for business is not used here.

Comment: Fully understand that. Its only to inform you that Lync 2010 is very soon EOL as it already reached the End of Mainstream support as written [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/de/articles/skypeforbusiness/312-end-of-mainstream-support-for-lync-2010.html). So your Lync Admin might already working on a move towards Skype for Business which might affect your POC soon or later.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about that. Could you please help me out with the other points? I have a fair bit of idea on what to do, but just need an advise from somebody who has been there done that.